# validation getting failed in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api

In laravel controller validation getting failed, please help.

[image]

Repository: https://github.com/dhawlesudhir/basic_app.git

*ProductController.php*:

```
  protected function validateRequest()
        {
            return request()->validate([
                'name' => 'required|min:10|max:255',
                'price' => 'required|integer|min:100',
                'category_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id'
            ]);
        }
    
        public function store()
        {
        
            $data = $this->validateRequest();
        
            $product = Product::create($data); 
    
            return new ProductResource($product);
        }
```

*api.php*:

```
Route::apiResource('/products', ProductController::class);
```

Comment: Have you set the Content-type to application/json in headers ? in postman

Answer (score 0):

Laravel throwing validation because you haven't set `json` in postman.
I can see currently you have set `Text`.

Set type to json like in screenshot

[image]

Otherwise Laravel receives  empty array from `request()->all()`

Also make sure to set header `Accept:application/json` .